# IN as an unsupported currency in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

i have integrated a paypal pro payment gateway in my website for my indian client. now ive seen the countries list paypal is available and it is available in india!

i integrated the paypal pro successfully with sandbox and using **US** as a default currency. which worked well, but when i changed my currency to **IN** i got this response.

```
Transaction Un-successful!
There was an error with your credit card processing:
Error Code: 99998
Error Message: Currency is not supported
```

now i looked over the internet and got the idea that **INR** is not supported in paypal as a payment currency, my question is how will i use paypal in a country where paypal are providing services but not their currency?

the pricing of whole website will be in indian rupees? how will i receive indian rupees as an currency in paypal pro? or is there any other way? any other payment gateway perhaps?
i'm really i need of help,i will highly appreciate any sort of help, because this is an conceptual issue i can't do anything if i dont know what to do.

Comment: What is the `IN` currency? Isn't it `INR`?

Comment: sorry INR i will update my question

Comment: INR currently opens to Partner and selected merchant only and no domestic payment are accepted yet in India. PayPal only allowed cross-border transaction using USD currencies. One more thing. PayPal pro only available to some merchant country such US, Canada and UK.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, As of now, Paypal is **not** supporting Payflow Pro Yet.

It is supporting **only WPS and Express Checkout**. Hope paypal will support it soon.

Lets all wait for paypal to support Payflow pro.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have used paypal pro(on website payment) a year ago i worked on sandbox as well couple of days ago works fine! are you talking about something else?